# Trying to make pictures scaleable, but also the same size

Tags: html, css, image, size, scale

So I have succeeded in making the images scale well, but they are not the same size even though they are all under the same CSS.

```css
.shirts {
height: auto;
max-width: 100%;
border: 1px solid white;
}
```

Here is an image of the actual website

[image: image of website]

Some of the images are taller than others and I need them to all be the same size, but also scale to the screen size.

Comment: So what size do you want them to be? E.G. you want each to be 20% of the window width, or what?

Comment: They are in a table so each of them should take up 100% of their respective TD cell

Comment: And you don't know how many table cells there will be?

Comment: Each table row is 4 cells wide. And I have also noticed that each column seems to have to same dimensions, for example, the first column is a perfect square of the correct size, and the second column is too tall, then the third column is fine again, and the forth column is a little too tall once more.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I seem to have found an answer to my own question, everything lines up correctly now that the TD height and widths have all been set equally, not entirely sure why I didn't try that from the beginning but better late than never.